# df -h shows only half the disk space I thought I had?

Tags: debian, disk-usage

I'm working on a DigitalOcean Debian droplet that in theory is supposed to offer 640GB of disk.

When I do `df -h` this is what I see:

```
Filesystem                 Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                     315G  286G   14G  96% /
udev                        10M     0   10M   0% /dev
tmpfs                      6.4G  200K  6.4G   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-label/DOROOT  315G  286G   14G  96% /
tmpfs                      5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                       13G  4.0K   13G   1% /run/shm
```

It looks to me like only 320GB is really available, but it's duplicated somehow.

Have I misunderstood how disk space works?

Most of this is a large Postgres database, but I was paying for the 640GB droplet on the basis that I could have a database that was at least 400GB.

Comment: check partitions, maybe postgres use raw partition(s) to store data

Comment: Why not raise an inquiry with DigitalOcean Support
https://www.digitalocean.com/company/contact/ Couldn't hurt. The duplication that you are seeing does not account in any way for the missing space. It is probably due to the way the mounts have been setup on the system.

Comment: try using `fdisk -l` to understand the disk partitioning

Comment: Or cat /proc/partitions.

Comment: How did it look when you first created the droplet?

Answer (score 1):

By running `fdisk -l` you can see the disk's partition layout, and if then either one or two things could happen:

## 1#

If it was a partitioning error, and there is nothing important on the other partition(s), then you could reset the partition table... But if there **was** something important in the other partition(s) than you could always back it up before resetting it.

## 2#

If it was not, then you could always do as *user55570* suggested, and report it to DigitalOcean..,

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/disk/by-label/DOROOT` and `rootfs` are both shown as mounted on `/` and have the same sizes. This should be a hint that it is in fact the same filesystem that is displayed twice. `rootfs` is a special name for the root filesystem; it's shown instead of the path to a device due to the peculiar way in which the root filesystem is mounted (not a peculiarity of your system specifically, this is very common). On your system, `df` isn't smart enough to figure out the double listing, probably because of the virtualization system.

Since you're using a virtual environment, it's possible that the filesystem size that you see is in fact the total filesystem size, which several users share. Whether that's the case or not depends on how the system is configured by your hosting provider.

In any case, you don't have twice 315GB, only at most once.